# Gradient of a function handle

Tags: matlab, gradient

I'm trying to calculate the gradient of a function handle in Matlab, for later use.

e.G:

```
fun = @(x) x(1)^2+ 2*x(2)

grad_fun = @(x) gradient(fun(x))
```

If I check this with: `grad_fun([1;1])` I receive 0.

For all values, all I get are zeroes.

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is result of `grad_fun([1;10])`?

Comment: the result is:   ans  =    0

Comment: if you want calculate grad_fun([1;10]) , first this pass to fun and because fun=@(x) x(1)^2+2x(2) and x=[1;10] so fun will be fun([1;2])=1^2+2*2 and fun=5 and gradient(5) or fun(any scalar number) will be 0(zero)

Answer (score 1):

first to create a function with a handle and symbolic variables

```
syms x y z

fxyz = @(x,y,z) x^2+y^2-2*z^2+z*log(x)
```

you can simply differentiate with respect to one variable at a time.

first d/dx then d/dy and so on...

```
Dx = diff(fxyz,x)
Dy = diff(fxyz,y)
Dz = diff(fxyz,z)
```

Finally combining these all to a function

```
nabla = [Dx, Dy, Dz]
```

result would be

[image]

note that this a symbolic class. You need to use subs() to evaluate this function at some point lets say p = (1,2,3)

```
ans = sum(subs(nabla,[x y z], [1 2 3]))
ans = -3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fun` inline function returns a scalar value. In other words, you tried to get gradient of a constant. 
The single argument of the `gradient` function must be a matrix or a row vector. See [MathWorks Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) for details.